# Does every basic exponent property have a corresponding logarithm property and vice versa?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, arithmetic, exponentiation

Here is what I'm referring to:

For $0 < a \neq 1$, $\,0 < b \neq 1$, and $m,n \in \mathbb{R^+}$, $p = a^m$, $q = a^n,$
$$\begin{align*}
a^0 &= 1 \qquad &\qquad \log_a(1) &= 0 \tag{a}\\[1ex]
a^1 &= a \qquad &\qquad \log_a(a) &=1 \tag{b}\\[1ex]
a^m a^n &= a^{m + n} \qquad &\qquad \log_a(pq) &= \log_a(p) + \log_a(q) \tag{c}\\[1ex]
\frac{a^m}{a^n} &= a^{m - n} \qquad &\qquad \log_a\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) &= \log_a(p) - \log_a(q) \tag{d}\\[1ex]
(a^m)^n &= a^{mn} \qquad &\qquad \log_a(p^n) &= n\log_a(p) \tag{e}\\[1ex]
\text{(Eq. 1)}& \qquad &\qquad \log_{a^m}(q) &= \frac{1}{m} \log_a(q) \tag{f}\\[1ex]
\text{(Eq. 2)}& \qquad &\qquad \log_a(p) &= \frac{\log_b(p)}{\log_b(a)} \Leftrightarrow \log_b(p) = \log_b(a) \log_a(p) \tag{g}\\[1ex]
a^m b^m &= (ab)^m \qquad &\qquad \text{(Eq. 3)}& \tag{h}
\end{align*}$$

My question is, do equations $1\unicode{x2013}3$ exist? I've been trying to find the right corresponding expressions but to no avail. Thank you.

Comment: The logarithm expression in (f) is just a special case of the one in (g): $\log_{a^m}(n) = (\log_a (n))/( \log_a (a^m))$, where the denominator becomes $m$. Both are change-of-base formulas. Their exponential counterpart is, I believe, the one in (h). Changes of base are weird and kinda break logarithms, and that's just an opinion... but I can't think of any other appropriate expression.

Comment: Your use of $m$ and $n$ in both columns, while technically correct, is a *little* confusing to read, since the variables serve different purposes on each side. I would write, say,
$$a^m a^n = a^{m+n} \qquad \log_a(pq)=\log_a p+\log_a q$$
where the properties are linked by taking $p=a^m$ and $q=a^n$.

Comment: @Blue ah yes I figured that could be confusing which is why I did not put $\iff$ in between them since they are not implications but merely analogues. I think I will edit the notations now, thank you.